# Modern way to consume a json based flask api with javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm new to web programming, I been learning the basics of Flask such as http requests, template inheritance, flask forms, saving data on the database etc.

I saw that some people only use flask as backend and its api its json based, and for the frontend they use React. Since I'm learning the basics of JavaScipt I don't want to use libraries like React or Jquery, I want to use just JavaScript. I was searcing and found that many people use AJAX with Jquery, or axios to consume an api. Is there any way to consume my flask api with just JavaScript without using any library or framework?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Yes, I suggest you keep reading. There are many tutorials out there about how to make a request to a REST API. AJAX with vanilla JavaScript or a library such as jquery or axios will work.

Comment: You've asked a series of questions, not just one, but the way SO works, you need to ask just one non-opinion-based question per question. *"Is there any way to consume my flask api with just JavaScript without using any library or framework?"* is a very different question to *"Some releated readings for a begginer?"* and *"Do people in real world use jinja2 and template inheritance for the frontend , just javascript or a mix of both?"*

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to consume my flask api with just JavaScript without using any library or framework?

Yes, using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), which is built in to all modern browsers. A query for data transmitted in JSON format looks like this:

In a non-async function, if you **are** returning the result of the last call to `then`:

```
// Do the request
return fetch("/path/to/the/data", {/*...options if any...*/})
.then(response => {
    // Check for HTTP success (`fetch` only rejects on *network* failure)
    if (!response.ok) {
        // HTTP error
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    // Read the body of the response and parse it from JSON into objects and such
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // ...`data` has the data from the call, parsed and ready to go
});
```

...or if you aren't:

```
// Do the request
return fetch("/path/to/the/data", {/*...options if any...*/})
.then(response => {
    // Check for HTTP success (`fetch` only rejects on *network* failure)
    if (!response.ok) {
        // HTTP error
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    // Read the body of the response and parse it from JSON into objects and such
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // ...`data` has the data from the call, parsed and ready to go
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...something went wrong, handle/report `error`...
});
```

`fetch` uses [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), so you'll want to read up on those.

In an `async` function, if you *are* allowing errors to propagate to the caller:

```
// Do the request
const response = await fetch("/path/to/the/data", {/*...options if any...*/});

// Check for HTTP success (`fetch` only rejects on *network* failure)
if (!response.ok) {
    // HTTP error
    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
}

// Read the body of the response and parse it from JSON into objects and such
const data = await response.json();

// ...`data` has the data from the call, parsed and ready to go
```

or if you aren't:

```
try {
    // Do the request
    const response = await fetch("/path/to/the/data", {/*...options if any...*/});

    // Check for HTTP success (`fetch` only rejects on *network* failure)
    if (!response.ok) {
        // HTTP error
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }

    // Read the body of the response and parse it from JSON into objects and such
    const data = await response.json();

    // ...`data` has the data from the call, parsed and ready to go
} catch (error) {
    // ...something went wrong, handle/report `error`...
}
```

More about `async` functions [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: (FWIW, I go into promises in detail in Chapter 8 and go into `async` function sin detail in Chapter 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The new Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)